# create a mp3 player embedded in a facebook post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The Serial podcast has this cool feature where they share their webpage on their facebook page and Facebook lets the audio be played within Facebook.  See this image:

[image]

I've created a blog post with all of the proper meta tags to match the relevant tags expected by facebook:

music:preview_url:url, the og:type is music.song, etc.

But I can't get a mp3 player to appear.

When I compare the open graph meta data in the Facebook debugger from the Serial webpage to my own webpage, the tags match up fine.  Yes, mine has a 'locale' array but that can't be the issue.

I'm thinking they must have some type of Facebook app?  Or I don't know what.  I've never built a Facebook app so if you think that is how they are doing it, where would I start looking?

This is my non-working open graph output:

[image]

This is the one from the Serial podcast.  You can see in the Share Dialog the player buttons for the MP3.  How are they getting that in there?  I would have thought just be me using the correct meta tags, Facebook would put player buttons on top of my mp3 and create the player for me.

[image]

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music: _“Facebook Open Graph Music is only available to whitelisted partners at this time.”_

Comment: Music stories http://media.fb.com/2015/11/05/music-stories-a-better-way-to-discover-and-share-music/